# GIMP: "Joined" arabic text

Tags: gimp, text, arabic

I'm trying to create an image which contains Arab text.

This is the (HTML entities for the) text: العربية

Raw, it is العربية

When I paste the text into GIMP, I select and correctly get RTL (right to left) text, but the characters are not "joined", as described at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Arabic.

If I paste into Word, it comes out OK.

I'm using GIMP 2.6.8 on Windows 7 64 bit.

Is there a way to persuade GIMP to render the text joined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to the latest version of GIMP (2.6.11 at the time of writing) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 1):

hey try this [The Solution i found for Arabic text Problem](http://registry.gimp.org/node/22257)

Comment: Thanks for that.  I ended up installing the latest version of GIMP which fixed the problem.  I'm not going to accept your answer, because, well, it didn't directly answer my question.  That said, it definitely helped me.  I would vote it up, but I don't have enough reputation...

Comment: you can post you own answer and then accept it at your own i wont mind but just finish this question so everyone can know answer and question sud be closed :)

Comment: As a new user, I couldn't post my own answer for 8 hours.  I've just done so, but I have to wait another 13 hours to accept it.

Comment: LOL,your amazing mate

Comment: This link is broken.